# Sort table with some criteria

Tags: jquery, datatables

JQuery's [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) has very poor docs. So sorry for maybe trivial question.

I want for filter my table by some string on some column. Here is mine code:

```
var str = "days";
my_table.fnFilter(str, 9);
```

I expect to have only rows that contains "days" string at 9 column (counting from 0). But above code does not bring me result

I have tried to use this code with RexEx:

```
var regEx = "days"; 
my_table.fnFilter(regEx, 9, true);
```

this code:

```
var regEx = "^days$";
my_table.fnFilter(regEx, 9, true);
```

and this code:

```
var regEx = ".*days.*";
my_table.fnFilter(regEx, 9, true);
```

All without luck. I am sure my table has **"101 days"** string at 9 column. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** I have custom type for my column:

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['days-asc'] = function (a, b) {
    var x = parseInt((trim(a) == "") ? 0 : trim(a.replace(/days/, "")));
    var y = parseInt((trim(b) == "") ? 0 : trim(b.replace(/days/, "")));
    return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
};

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['days-desc'] = function (a, b) {
    var x = parseInt((trim(a) == "") ? 0 : trim(a.replace(/days/, "")));
    var y = parseInt((trim(b) == "") ? 0 : trim(b.replace(/days/, "")));
    return ((x < y) ? 1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));
};
```

**UPDATE 2:**
My initialization *options* for table:

```
 $.my_table = $("#myTable").dataTable({
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "bStateSave": false,
    "bFilter": true,
    "bSort": true,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "oLanguage": {
        "sLengthMenu": sStdMenu + " per page"
    },
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "sDom": 'rti<"bottom2"p><"bottom1"l',
    "aaSorting": [
        [0,'asc']
    ],
    "aoColumns": [
        { "sType": "html-trimmed" },
        { "sType": "date-direct" },
        { "sType": "date-direct" },
        { "sType": "html" },
        { "sType": "percent" },
        { "sType": "money" },
        { "sType": "money" },
        { "sType": "money" },
        { "sType": "days" },            
        { "sType": "days" },
        { "sType": "days" },
        { "sType": "days" },
        { "sType": "days" },
        { "sType": "days" },
        { "sType": "html" },
        { "sType": "html" },
        null,
        null,
        null
    ]

});
```

Comment: Can you show us your `dataTable` initialization options?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your initialization code, or your syntax for the `fnFilter` function. If it helps, here's a full example of the `fnFilter` function with all parameters set to their default values (except for `filterString` and `column`):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    var my_table = $('#example').dataTable(),
        filterDataTable = function filterDataTable() {
            var filterString = 'days',
                column = 9,
                treatAsRegex = false,
                smartFiltering = true,
                showFilter = true,
                caseInsensitive = true;
            my_table.fnFilter(filterString, column, treatAsRegex, smartFiltering, showFilter, caseInsensitive);
        };
    $('#someElement').click(function (e) {
        filterDataTable();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Also, on a completely unrelated note, your sorting functions could be simplified to:

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['days-asc'] = function (a, b) {
    var x = parseInt(a, 10) || 0,
        y = parseInt(b, 10) || 0;
    return x - y;
};
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['days-desc'] = function (a, b) {
    var x = parseInt(a, 10) || 0,
        y = parseInt(b, 10) || 0;
    return y - x;
};
```